# Проверка Recaptcha

Tags: javascript, joomla, recaptcha

Подключаю поле Recaptcha к странице регистрации пользователя - при нажатии на кнопку "Отправить" данные отправляются, и только после этого происходит проверка - страница перезагружена, и на экране ошибка: "Вы ввели неправильный код Recaptcha". Есть ли какая-нибудь функция для JavaScript, отсылающая запрос на сервер Google и возвращающая ответ, правильно ли был введен код или нет? Поле Recaptcha генерируется системой.

Comment: Вы зарегистрировались в Recaptcha и получили коды доступа к ней для приложения?

Comment: Да. Отображается все нормально, проблема только в том, что проверка происходит не в реальном времени, а после перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: А вы думали рекапча работает в реальном времени? Она обрабатывается при самбите формы. Другого варианта не видел.

Comment: Если на странице стоит 2 и более рекапч, то такая проверка не работает. Есть функция как проверить 2 и более капчи на странице без перезагрузки?

Answer (score 1):

На данный момент актуальная версия API для reCAPTCHA 2. Много чего реализовали и подправили.

Проверка на нажатие пользователем кнопки (JS, с подключенным ***https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js***):

```
if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == ""){
    alert("Подтвердите, что Вы не являетесь роботом!");
    return false;
} else {
    alert("Спасибо что прошли проверку!");
    return true;
}
```

Саму валидацию нужно оставить на стороне сервера (вдруг у пользователя выключен JS).

Answer (score 1):

Раз уж дух поднял вопрос, напишу я немного более более подробный ответ:

> Есть ли какая-нибудь функция для JavaScript, отсылающая запрос на
>   сервер Google и возвращающая ответ, правильно ли был введен код или нет

Нет, все не так просто. Каптча - это штука которая нужна для ограничения доступа к каким-то ресурсам. Если все проверки проводить только на клиенте, бот их с легкостью проигнорирует, это обычно гораздо проще чем научить бота проходить каптчу.

Другими словами представьте, что на главный вход в здание Вы поставили сканер сетчатки и автоматчиков, а черный вход - не закрыли. Злоумышленник через него зайти не постесняется, а честных людей будут обыскивать при каждом входе.

Теперь, если необходимость валидации каптчи на сервере понятна, посмотрим как это в общих чертах устроено со стороны клиента:

1. Вы добавляете на страничку [виджет рекаптчи](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display). То есть в самом простом случае вставляете в html
2. Добавляете элемент в котором отрисуется каптча.
   Он должен содержать класс "g-recaptcha", и ключ сайта. Ключ получается из админки рекаптчи после регистрации в системе.
3. Recaptcha 2.0 (текущая актуальная) общается со своим бекендом асинхронно по умолчанию, никакой перезагрузки странички быть не должно. Но нам надо получить как-то ответ: для этого добавляем в наш элемент с капчой еще один параметр, "data-callback", содержащий имя функции-колбека которая выполнится когда юзер удачно пройдет капчу. Параметром функции будет ключ конкретной капчи, который вернет вам гугл.

   ```
   <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key" data-callback="mySuperFunctionDontCopyPaste"></div>

   function mySuperFunctionDontCopyPaste(captchaKey){
       // отдаем бэкенду captchaKey
   }
   ```
4. Итак, у нас есть некий ключ, сильно упрощая считаем что это имя конкретной каптчи. Мы этот ключ отдадим в запросе нашему бэкенду, и уже бэкенд спросит у гугла, "а все ли хорошо у каптчи с таким ключем?", а бекенд уже решает, что с этим знанием делать, можно куку какую-то нам дописать например, с которой нас будут пропускать к ресурсам защищенным каптчей.
5. Там есть еще несколько нюансов, и они расписаны в документации: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro. Документацию читать полезно.