# reCaptcha валидация

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

Идея в том, чтобы выводить сообщение об ошибке, если пользователь не ввел капчу. Но ошибка не выводится, в консоли тоже все чисто.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var onloadCallback = function() {
            grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
                'sitekey' : '...',//мой ключ
                'callback' : correctCaptcha
            });
        };

        var correctCaptcha = function(response) {};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<div id="html_element"></div>
<span id="errorCaptcha" style="color: red"></span>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSaveIt">Save</button>
</form>
<script>
    //валидация формы по нажатию на submit
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#btnSaveIt").click(function(){

           var isValid = true;

           if(correctCaptcha == ''){
               isValid = false;
               $("#errorCaptcha").html("Enter captcha");
           }else{
               $("#errorCaptcha").html("");
           }

           //еще if-ы для валидации других полей формы

           if(isValid == true){

           }else{
               return false;
           }
       });
    });
</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?
onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
    async defer>
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: какую версию капчи используете ? видимо не reCAPTCHA V2 ?

Comment: @Arsen именно она? сейчас дополню вопрос (скрипт в конце `body`)

Comment: Посмотрите ответы в этом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453260/186083 вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете версию капчи V2, то самый простой метод проверки это - было ли действие пользователь-капча, для этого необходимо проверить невидимую строку, которая генерируется самим `JS` капчи:

```
$("#btnSaveIt").click(function(){
var key = $('#g-recaptcha-response').val().trim();
if(key == ''){
console.log('Пользователь не взаимодействовал с капчой');
return false;
} else{
console.log('пользователь активировал капчу');

}
});
```

Тем самым вы уже можете проверить было ли действие со стороны пользователя, до отправки формы