# Как вернуть страницу назад чтобы все вводные данные сохранились

Tags: php

У меня есть форма заказа "order" и проверка через капчу.При отправке форма перенаправляется на страницу "ordergo" где проходит валидацыю. Когда пользователь ввел не правильно каптчу и отправил.Я проверяю  на валидацию этим кодом :

```
    if ($_POST['captcha'] != $_POST['inputCaptcha'])
 header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Но страница открывается уже без вводимых данных. Как сделать чтобы данные сохранялись .
код каптчи

```
$i=1;
    do
    {
        $num[$i] = mt_rand(0,9);
        echo "<img  src=\"../../i/numbers/".$num[$i].".png\" width=15 height=15> ";
        $i++;
    }
    while ($i<7);
    $captcha = $num[1].$num[2].$num[3].$num[4].$num[5].$num[6];

    ?>

    <input name="captcha" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $captcha ;?>">
    <input name="pr" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6"></p>
```

Comment: какая версия капчи ? v1?

Comment: Может вы подскажите лучший вариант.

Comment: Но вы не ответили на вопрос )) хотя наверно понятно, если пользователь вводит капчу - это первая версия. V1 уже устарела, используйте как минимум вторую версию, а как проверить взаимодействовал ли пользователь до отправки данных, прочитайте тут։  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/699532/recaptcha-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/699537#699537

Comment: Как вариант: проверяйте капчу с помощью ajax - тогда не будет перезагружаться страница и, соответственно, не потеряются данные. Это самый простой вариант. Можно также записывать данные в localStorage и выводить их при перезагрузке страницы, но это уже "танцы с бубном"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сохранить данные можно с помощью Cookie или как предложил @humster_spb, Ajax (XMLTHttpRequest)
1) Путь через Cookie

```
/* Отправили запрос на авторизации
Код авторизации */
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])){
setcookie("name",$_POST['name']);
}
if (isset($_POST['password'])){
setcookie("password",$_POST['password']);
}
//TODO валидация данных
```

В шаблоне  ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])

```
    <form action="/auth/" method="POST">
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_COOKIE['name'])?$_COOKIE['name']:"";?> />
<input type="password" value="<?php echo isset($_COOKIE['password'])?$_COOKIE['password']:"";?> />
    <input type="submit>
    </form>
```

Comment: Авторизация или order(ordergo) не имеет смысла, механизм один